# Why is there progress callback information printed when using backgroundSession to upload tasks in the background

Tags: objective-c, background, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I would like to ask a question when I was in the background with `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier` upload task encountered the following problem:

**Background**: I have a lot of uploading task (assuming that there are 200), I will create 200 jobs in a for loop, to join the queue, queue maximum number of concurrent is 4, I use `backgroundSession` to upload, and I  implements `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` method in the `APPDelegate`, and print some info (`interceptApplication` called for `URLSession`), then implements `NSURLSession` `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession` agent method, and invokes the `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` `completionHandler` (and print the log `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession`).

**Question**:

1. I found that the progress information will be print after program enter background (but I checked the information and said that there would be no progress callback during background upload, and only called `didCompleteWithError` method for each task after all background tasks were completed).
2. Because the task a lot, I am in `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` and `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession` output information will be printed many times, I thought that  all task can be completed, but I find the program will stop  printing log message after Running for a period of time.

Any help is appreciated.